# How can I keep broccoli flowers from forming the same day the bud appears?

Tags: brassicas

I'm growing purple broccoli, and the petals from the flower on top is forming the same day that it appears. How can I prevent this from happening so quickly?

It's forming white petals if you're curious about the color?

It's been in the 90s all week in MN USDA 4A.

Comment: it can help to fold the one of the topmost leaves over the flower itself - this will wind up snapping the leaf, but does not significantly affect the plant.

Answer (score 1):

Too hot broccoli  is a cold weather  crop.